# Get parent child data from mongodb nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new in mongodb I am just starting mongodb with nodejs.I dont know how to get comments array. My document looks:

```
{
   "__v": NumberInt(0),
   "_id": ObjectId("565443b1172e19d51f98b0ed"),
   "address": "tohana",
   "comments": [
     {
       "_id": ObjectId("5654455fe088d89c20736e3c"),
       "comment": "good man",
       "uemail": "dinesh@gmail.com",
       "uname": "dinesh" 
    },
     {
       "_id": ObjectId("565445e471dce6ca20705a84"),
       "comment": "nice person",
       "uemail": "kr@gmail.com",
       "uname": "krishan" 
    },
     {
       "_id": ObjectId("5654460e7aa73bec2064060e"),
       "comment": "bad person",
       "uemail": "Rai",
       "uname": "Rahul" 
    } 
  ],
   "email": "nishantg@ocodewire.com"▼,
   "name": "Nishant" 
}
```

I want to fetch comments data by id.My code is:

```
var Users = require("../app/models/users");// model
app.get('/commentsEdit/:id', function(req, res) {
var id = req.params.id;//here is comment id



 res.send({data:id});

})
```

Comment: Just starting. So please do some reading: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/crud/.

Comment: can you please share how can i get child data?

Comment: I don't think I should write bits of your application for you, no. You need to do some baisic research effort that is sorely lacking from your question. If you don't have any concept of what to put in that block, then reading the tutorial stages starting at that link will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Users = require("../app/models/users");// model
app.get('/commentsEdit/:id1/:id2', function(req, res) {
var id1 = req.params.id1;//here is user id
var id2 = req.params.id2;//here is comment id
Users.find({"_id": id1}, { comments: { $elemMatch: { _id: id2 }}})
     .exec(function(err, data) {
         if(err){
           console.log(err)
        }
        else{
          console.log(data);
        }
})
```